# Changing bulb in bathroom light fitting

Tags: lighting, bathroom

I've tried looking for guides, but I haven't seen any other lights like mine

[image]
[image]

It seems like there is a cover over the bulb but I haven't been able to remove it and even if I could I don't think the bulb could fit out.

I've tried twisting the white case but there is no movement.

I can't see any clips

There are some screws, but I haven't seen any other fittings that need anything unscrewed to get to the bulb.

The second picture shows how far I am able to pull the fitting out

Comment: Have you tried to separate the white cover from the base by just pulling it down?

Comment: It might require some prying to get off if you haven’t tried that yet and you can’t find any other way I would try prying it loose with a flathead screwdriver

Comment: Perhaps that cover twists off

Comment: i have the same ones in my kitchen. there's no twisting at all, everything pulls apart. there's a tight-fitting sleeve bracket over the GU10 bulb that slides off. they can be quite stuck in there, watch your knuckles when yanking. i would upgrade to LED replacements.

Comment: @dandavis, sounds like an answer.